# What $ sign indicates in a folder path in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that has a two $ signs like this :

```
$folderDest= '/Home/Vars/Cust/V1/Ex/Res/$toDo/$done'
```

what $toDo and $done stand for?

Note: I don't have these variables anywhere in the script.

Edit: The code below.

```
$month = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM
$ftppath = $folderDest+ "/" + $month + "/*$xttz.txt"
```

Comment: If you don't have these variables defined anywhere, they are cosidered `$null`, so $folderDest will become `'/Home/Vars/Cust/V1/Ex/Res//'`

Comment: @Theo that would require use of `"` instead of `'`

Comment: Good point by @MathiasR.Jessen. Currently, the path is surrounded by single quotes and in that case, the `$toDo\$done` will be returned as literal text: `'/Home/Vars/Cust/V1/Ex/Res/$toDo/$done'`. When surrounded by double-quotes `"/Home/Vars/Cust/V1/Ex/Res/$toDo/$done"`, the values will be interpreted by PowerShell and valued `$null`

Comment: Can you show the whole script, or at least the line/context in which `$folderDest` is being used later in the script?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen 

$month = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM

$ftppath = $folderDest+ "/" + $month + "/*$xttz.txt"

Comment: Well, now you have to show us where `$ftppath` is being used, to be sure :-P But I suspect it's simply the literal folder names on the ftp server - plenty of file systems (NTFS included) support `$` as file or directory name characters

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Usage : 
Receive-WinSCPItem -WinSCPSession $session -Path $ftppath -Destination $destpath....  I do think these are literal folder names. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$folderDest= '/Home/Vars/Cust/V1/Ex/Res/$toDo/$done'
```

In PowerShell the value of $folderDest will be interpreted as:
/Home/Vars/Cust/V1/Ex/Res/$toDo/$done

This is due to the single quotes around it as defined in [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1).